# How to scrape specific part of online english dictionary?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

Hello experts and friends from all over the world.
I'm a non-english speaker who's learning english recently, and from last week I have been making huge english vocabulary list which contains phonetic alphabet, meaning etc.
Problem is some of word's phonetic alphabet were missing, due to those are non-exist on few of online dictionaries I have checked. But after struggling for a while, I found oxford online dictionary having those phonetic alphabet I couldn't found out before.
So, here's what I want to do. I'd like to make automated excel word list that searches and copy phonetic alphabet from oxford dictionary.
It is because huge amount of words range, I cannot copy and paste all of them one by one manually. (actually I still have over 7k words to fill in its phonetic alphabet)

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/

There are British accent and American accent you can find. I only want copy american phonetic alphabet from oxford dictionary.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/absolutely?q=absolutely

Why I want phonetic alphabet from oxford dictionary first? It is because those fonts are clear and easy to read, better than other english dictionaries online.

For word 'absolutely', I found what I want like below; ( æbsəluːtli )is my goal to get.

```
<span class="red">NAmE</span>
<span class="phon" eid="absolutely_phon_10" dpsid="ubd078dc7731dc33e.684f08cc.1604f657bf7.-7536">
<span class="name">NAmE</span><span class="separator">/</span>
<span class="wrap">/</span>ˈæbsəluːtli<span class="wrap">/</span><span class="separator">/</span></span>
```

There is another type, like word 'declaring' is -ing form.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/declare#declare_inflg_2
It is hiding under the drop down menu.

```
<span class="heading">Verb Forms</span>
<span class="phon" eid="declare_phon_46" dpsid="u4bd66fe39eed907e.-606459e9.16674bee79e.273c">
<span class="name">NAmE</span>
<span class="separator">/</span><span class="wrap">/</span>dɪˈklerɪŋ<span class="wrap">/</span>
<span class="separator">/</span></span>
```

I don't have enough knowledge to get what I wanted, I still have long way to go. All of sudden I feel crawling or scraping data is interesting because I could fill out my vocabulary list on excel.

Could anyone give some idea how to finish my excel word list up successfully?

Here's oxford3000 list for test
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlist/english/oxford3000/

thanks

Comment: I would suggest you put aside a day or two to go through some tutorials starting with these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrPEAljQjRM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB1O30fR-EE&list=PLillGF-RfqbZTASqIqdvm1R5mLrQq79CU . You will then be able to more confidently search on StackOverflow for Question/Answers that will help get you started. Also, look into whether there is an API for this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I guess I really need to learn html and vba. By the way, I guess you mean API of below right? https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/   unfortunately I couldn't get phonetic alphabet from this, and I noticed it is a paid service. Also, I don't really know what API is. LOL

Comment: Public API would be a documented interface from the site that would provide an easy way to access info from the site.  https://www.howtogeek.com/343877/what-is-an-api/.    There are plenty of languages you can web scrape in and return data to Excel. For this task, if only looking for 3000 word > phonetic then VBA is likely fine.

Comment: You will need to have some familiarity with HTML and HTMLDocument methods e.g. getElementsByTagName...... I would also recommend learning about [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: I'm just having a read of the API documentation now.

Comment: Ok... so you can make 1000 free calls in a month with Prototype account. The next best, depending on how many calls you wish to make looks like the 10,001 calls (that one extra PAYG call halves the price). # calls will be affected by whether word is head word or needs lemmas lookup call first. The endpoint construction you need is GET /entries/{source_lang}/{word_id}?fields=pronunciations  though that doesn't seem to filter massively. Code examples are given. I used the python and clicked expand operations on [this](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation) to see filter added.

Comment: Dead easy with python.With vba you can use the .Net example as an outline in terms of 3 headers you need to add. The rest goes in the url string you construct with the head word. You will need a json parser to handle the json returned e.g. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

Comment: That's if you want to go the API route. Otherwise, see the links I already gave for xmlhttp or internetexplorer scraping. See also: https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: Thanks again for your attention, I'll review them step by step.