# I'm getting stuck at vba runtime error 424

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm getting

> run-time error 424
>
> in 68th row (line)
>
> request.Open "GET", Url, False

and I don't know how to fix it.

My previous question I posted ;
[How to scrape specific part of online english dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123054/how-to-scrape-specific-part-of-online-english-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment104479745_59123054)

My final goal is to get result like this;

```
    A          B
beginning   bɪˈɡɪnɪŋ
behalf      bɪˈhæf
behave      bɪˈheɪv
behaviour   bɪˈheɪvjər
belong      bɪˈlɔːŋ
below       bɪˈloʊ
bird        bɜːrd
biscuit     ˈbɪskɪt
```

Here's code I wrote, and it's mostly based on someone else's code I found on internet.

```
'   Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
'   Microsoft XML, v3.0
'   Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions

Sub ParseHelp()

    ' Word reference from
    Dim Url As String
    Url = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Value
   
    ' Get dictionary's html
    Dim Html As String
    Html = GetHtml(Url)
    
    ' Check error
    If InStr(Html, "<TITLE>Not Found</Title>") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "404"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Extract phonetic alphabet from HTML
    Dim wrapPattern As String
    wrapPattern = "<span class='name' (.*?)</span>"
    Set wrapCollection = FindRegexpMatch(Html, wrapPattern)
    ' MsgBox StripHtml(CStr(wrapCollection(1)))
    
    ' Fill phonetic alphabet into cell
    If Not wrapCollection Is Nothing Then
        Dim wrap As String
        
        On Error Resume Next
            wrap = StripHtml(CStr(wrapCollection(1)))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            wrap = ""
        End If
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value = wrap
    Else
        MsgBox "not found"
    End If

End Sub

Public Function StripHtml(Html As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    Dim sOut As String
    
    Html = Replace(Html, "</li>", vbNewLine)
    Html = Replace(Html, "&nbsp;", " ")
    
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "<[^>]+>"
    End With
    
    sOut = RegEx.Replace(Html, "")
    StripHtml = sOut
    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function

Public Function GetHtml(Url As String) As String
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    Dim converter As New ADODB.stream
    
    ' Get
    request.Open "GET", Url, False
    request.send
    
    ' raw bytes
    converter.Open
    converter.Type = adTypeBinary
    converter.Write request.responseBody
    
    ' read
    converter.Position = 0
    converter.Type = adTypeText
    converter.Charset = "utf-8"
    
    ' close
    GetHtml = converter.ReadText
    converter.Close

End Function

Public Function FindRegexpMatch(txt As String, pat As String) As Collection
    Set FindRegexpMatch = New Collection

    Dim rx As New RegExp
    Dim matcol As MatchCollection
    Dim mat As Match
    Dim ret As String
    Dim delimiter As String
    
    txt = Replace(txt, Chr(10), "")
    txt = Replace(txt, Chr(13), "")

    rx.Global = True
    rx.IgnoreCase = True
    rx.MultiLine = True
    rx.Pattern = pat
    Set matcol = rx.Execute(txt)
    'MsgBox "Match:" & matcol.Count
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    For Each mat In matcol
        'FindRegexpMatch.Add mat.SubMatches(0)
        FindRegexpMatch.Add mat.Value

    Next mat
    Set rx = Nothing
  
      
   ' Insert code that might generate an error here
   Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
   ' Insert code to handle the error here
   MsgBox "FindRegexpMatch. " & Err.GetException()
   Resume Next
    
End Function
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: I just edited my question above. It's located at 68th row.     /   request.Open "GET", Url, False

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of how to read in values from column A and write out pronounciations to column B. It uses css selectors to match a child node then steps up to parentNode in order to ensure entire pronounciation is grabbed. There are a number of ways you could have matched on the parent node to get the second pronounciation. Note that I use a parent node and `Replace` as the pronounciation may span multiple childNodes.

If doing this for lots of lookups please be a good netizen and put some waits in the code so as to not bombard the site with requests.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutPronounciations()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim data As String, lastRow As Long, urls()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'you need at least two words in column A or change the redim.
    urls = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value)

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(urls))

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .Open "GET", "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/" & urls(i), False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            data = Replace$(Replace$(html.querySelector(".name ~ .wrap").ParentNode.innerText, "/", vbNullString), Chr$(10), Chr$(32))
            results(i) = Right$(data, Len(data) - 4)
        Next
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(results, 1), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Required references (VBE>Tools>References):

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

Should you go down the [API route](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/) then here is a small example.  You can make 1000 free calls in a month with Prototype account. The next best, depending on how many calls you wish to make looks like the 10,001 calls (that one extra PAYG call halves the price). # calls will be affected by whether word is head word or needs lemmas lookup call first. The endpoint construction you need is `GET /entries/{source_lang}/{word_id}?fields=pronunciations` though that doesn't seem to filter massively.  You will need a json parser to handle the json returned e.g. github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas. Download raw code from there and add to standard module called JsonConverter. You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutPronounciations()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim data As String, lastRow As Long, words()

    'If not performing lemmas lookup then must be head word e.g. behave, behalf
    Const appId As String = "yourAppId"
    Const appKey As String = "yourAppKey"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    words = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value)

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(words))

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim json As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
            .Open "GET", "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-us/" & LCase$(words(i)) & "?fields=pronunciations", False
            .setRequestHeader "app_id", appId
            .setRequestHeader "app_key", appKey
            .setRequestHeader "ContentType", "application/json"
            .send
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            results(i) = IIf(json("results")(1)("type") = "headword", json("results")(1)("lexicalEntries")(1)("pronunciations")(2)("phoneticSpelling"), "lemmas lookup required")
            Set json = Nothing
        Next
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(results, 1), 1) = Application.Transpose(results)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It is nice to have your kind answers again. I have filled in just one word 'beginning' at 'A1', and newly copied your first code into module after I cleaned up code I wrote. Then I got run-time error 13 Type mismatch from line 9th. Anyway thank you very much, you're helping me a lot here.

Comment: you need at two words in column A or I can re-write code to handle case of one word only

Comment: I have put two words now, beginning and next. I got '-21470128 (80072efe)' run-time error.  (-___-);a   It says I got disconnected from server abnormally. I guess I got banned right?

Comment: I will have a look. Which method are you using? The top or the bottom? If the bottom, you need to be signed up to the API and use your own API credentials.

Comment: The top one. Json kind of thing is way beyond my understanding for my current situation, all I can do is collect resources about them. Hmm.... API seemes like pretty needed. But some of people done crawling entire dictionary from oxford, and even made mdx (mdict) dictionary, how they do that? Need to stop 1 or 2 seconds after search a word?

Comment: Ok.... so I ran top and I got _bɪˈɡɪnɪŋ_ and _nekst_ as response. Give it a few mins and try running for those two words again and verify code is same as posted above.

Comment: Code checked, option checked. I'm keep getting '-21470128 (80072efe)' run-time error. OTL

Comment: Do you have any kind of proxy that might be blocking traffic?

Comment: Not at all, the server probably blocked me with some unknown reason. I think I could try this again few more hours later and use VPN. If tests fails again, I should have consider to give up for a week. (-___-);;;

Comment: I've found out a solution that no longer need to search online dictionary directly. There's a mdx dictionary which is 99.9% exactly same as online's. You can download at ( https://mdx.mdict.org/%E5%85%AD%E5%A4%A7%E7%9F%A5%E5%90%8D%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E7%89%9B%E6%B4%A5_Oxford/Oxford%20Advanced%20Learner_s%20Dictionary%209th_%20By%20Amazon_%202016.9.27/  )   Also, there's a mdx server provides a HTTP interface to external tools. ( https://github.com/ninja33/mdx-server )

Comment: So by using these combination I can search mdx dictionary on my chrome browser offline, which means I have possibility to extract info from mdx file (which is huge advantage, no worry about API anymore). After downloaded them two, I ran the code again after I changed like this ->  .Open "GET", "http://localhost:8000/" & urls(i), False    and I got 91 runtime error. I think I'm close to my goal. Could you help me look into these new tools and check the code again? thank you very much!

Comment: For standalone use of mdx dictionary, you can have a GoldenDict to check any kind of mdx dictionary freely.  down >  http://goldendict.org/download.php  It's like small browser, you can also check source code like chrome by right clicking on target you wanna check out.

Comment: Hi! This should be the basis of a new question if using new tools etc..... Show what you have tried and explain where stuck.